# Opencv Xcode Linker Error for MacOSX

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, linker-errors

XCode version: 8.2.1 
Opencv version :3.2
Apple Mach-O Linker Error
ld: library not found for -ltcl8.6
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Am trying to run a simple Hello World program in opencv. I followed this tutorial https://blogs.wcode.org/2014/11/howto-setup-xcode-6-1-to-work-with-opencv-libraries/
http://tilomitra.com/opencv-on-mac-osx/
I do not know what the error is actually aiming at. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue and I will explain you the different steps to solve this problem

1. Download source of the last opencv on [Github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git).
2. Download the last version of cmake [Cmake download link](https://cmake.org/download/) and install it.
3. Go to the opencv folder and create a directory named build.
4. Go to **build** directory.

Don't forget to add cmake to the path :

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui 
                                   --install=/usr/local/bin
```

1. Launch the command :

   ```
   cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" ../
   ```
2. After you have to compile :

   ```
   make -j8
   ```
3. And to install it :

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```
4. Open Xcode and set on your project in build settings : "Header search path" : "/usr/local/include"
   "Library search path" : "/usr/local/lib"
5. On your project, right click and choose "add files to your project name"
6. Go to the directory "Opencv/build/lib" and select all ".dylib" files.

Now, you can use OpenCV 3.2 with the last version of Xcode.

Let me know, if you have another issue.